# random forest model performance measure

Tags: r, random-forest

This is a screenshot of my random forest model output, how can I interpret it? 
Does the final sentence "The final values used for the model were mtry = 6, splitrule = variance and min.node.size = 20." means that the performance measures are those next to the values where  mtry = 6, min.node.size = 20 that is RMSE 1.989648 (The value highlighted in red)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as the penultimate line says, RMSE was used to select the optimal model using the smallest value. Your highlighted line has the lowest RMSE and, hence, it was selected and you have three corresponding performance measures there.

Comment: Thank you! Does that also mean I need to rebuild the model with these values assigned to the corresponding parameters?

Comment: @user233531, no, the resulting object can already be used as the optimal model.

Comment: I appreciate helping me in understanding this: This is also the output from XGboost model: Stopping. 
    Best iteration:
    [555] train-rmse:1.811221+0.009737 test-rmse:1.971253+0.034602
which RMSE value is considered the measure for the model performance?

Comment: @user233531, in your original question RMSE as a measure had a clear purpose (used to select a model). In general, basically any output can be seen as a model performance measure. In your case too, everything is informative, but typically one cares more about the test-rmse as it shows how the model performs with *new* data.

Comment: Am I allowed to ask one more question or no?

Comment: @user233531, well, you can surely ask question that are directly related to your original question. The latter one wasn't too related, but sure, go ahead, at least I could recommend whether to post a new question here or on stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Ok, my question is can we say that in my case random forest outperformed Xgboost model based on the values provided?

Comment: @user233531, it's impossible for me to say just after seeing a couple of numbers. *If* two values of RMSE measure *the same thing* (same test set, etc.), then yes, the algorithm with the lowest RMSE performs best in this sense.